# Expedite the develop / deploy / run cycle with Spring, Maven and Wildfly

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, wildfly

I've just recently entered the Java world for a client of mine. I have 18 years experience as a .Net developer, but the Java side is new.

Coming from .Net, I'm used to expecting to be able to make a code change, compile my code and run it with a debugger attached all usually within sub 30 seconds, *maybe* 1 minute on large projects needing a full recompile.

I'm finding my current process with this Java project is taking me upwards of 5-6 minutes. Because of the long time and multiple steps, I find myself starting on other tasks or losing track of what I was doing.

**Here is my current process for making a change and testing it:**

- Make code change
- (~200s) Recompile code with Maven on the main Maven module `mvn clean install`. If I do `-DskipTests` I can save about 60 seconds here.
- (~5s) Stop Wildfly server
- (~5s) Copy `.war` file from `myproject\target\myproject.war` to `c:\wildfly\standalone\deploy\`
- (~90s) Start Wildfly server `c:\wildfly\bin\standalone.bat`
- Re-login to application (my session expired)
- Attach debugger

Again, it is not *only* the amount of time required for each of these steps but the fact that there are so many steps and the waiting time in-between each makes for distraction as well - *after all, who is going to sit and stare at a screen for a 3 minute compile*? Whatever I go off to do, I am surely not going to return to that screen at the exact moment the compile is complete. There is going to be wasted time in there.

Further more, I'm repeating this process every time I want to make a single code change.

**Is there a way to streamline this process?  I.e.:**

- Is there a way to join some of these steps
- Can I speed up the Wildfly boot process?
- What will speed Maven up?
- Can I do something like "Edit & Continue" which exists in .Net (i.e. live code changes).
- Is there a way to get around having to have Wildfly reinitialize anytime I deploy a new war?

Comment: Do you develop in Eclipse? Then you can use the WTP plugin to test code on a Wildfly. This will be _much_ faster.

Comment: @JFMeier, I do not. I'm developing using VS Code. The interface is much more friendly IMO, but I do realize that means I don't have access to this plugin you're referring to.

Comment: Java development is mainly done in Eclipse or IntelliJ. Both are mature IDEs that help you a lot.

Comment: the .NET experience you are looking for is basically what you get when you use Spring Boot and deploy applications as a standalone jar. The fact that you have an external container like Wildfly involved is what complicates matters. Assuming you're stuck with it, I do support the sentiment already expressed: use a proper IDE which has deployment support for JavaEE/JakartaEE containers. Visual Studio Code is a fantastic tool, but it's not the tool for this job.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: My answer includes processes I personally use, thus it may not be the optimum or most popular solution. Anyway, these things tend to be bound to developer's personal preference.

Find below some recommendations that could speed up the development process.

- **Use a proper IDE for Java development**

Using a popular java IDE can make development faster as it supports integration with build tools(Maven), Version Control Systems, Application Servers(Wildfly) and much more.

Popular choices are Eclipse, IntelliJ, Netbeans and much more.

- **Fast redeployment**

As I said above, a proper IDE would support integration with application servers, Wildfly for your case. By using a Wildfly IDE plugin, you can speed things up as you do not have to wait for app server to boot every time you make a code change. IDE starts once the server and then applies your changes to the running instance.

Personally, I also prefer to use a standalone Wildfly installation instead of integrating it with IDE. To achieve fast redeployment I use [hotswap agent](http://hotswapagent.org/). Note that you have to install DCEVM, an alternate JVM which however is not interfering with your main JVM.

Finally, to conclude it is understandable that you make a big turn from .NET to Java and you may feel lost at some points. I would advise to spend some time setting up your environment, and once you have finalised it and you feel comfortable, development will become much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Why stop, move the archive and re-start the server ?

Check out the following maven plugin which will allow you to automate at least that part of it..

https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/examples/deployment-example.html